# Unable to start the program while debugging the win32 project

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I am executing win32 C++ project in Visual studio 2010. My project is a simple project to create a dll.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyWin32Function.h"

// This is an example of an exported function.
extern "C" MYWIN32FUNCTION_API float fnMyWin32Function(float a,float b)
{
return a*b;
}
```

And i am able to build and rebuild the project successfully. But when i am trying to debug the project i am getting the following error.

> Unable to start the program
>   'c:\users\Visual studio 2010\projects\Mywin32Function\debug\Mywin32function.dll'

Answer (score 1):

It's simply telling you that you can't run a DLL. You need to build an executable that uses the DLL, and run the executable.

Comment: I want the dll to be use in another c# project. that's why i need to dll to add as a reference.

Comment: @GSReddy Create a C# project and add the dll reference. then you are ready to debug the C# project. as Jerry pointed out you cant execute a dll

Comment: @Jeeva: You can't add a reference to an umanaged DLL in a managed application. References only work for managed DLLs. You have to use platform invoke to call functions from unmanaged DLLs.